# HOW Dynamic Drive DHTML Scripts- Disable right mouse click script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

when the right mouse is clicked on the web page. Use it to stop surfers from easily saving your web page, viewing its source, or lifting images off your site when using either IE 4+ or NS 4+.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either jquery or just raw javascript for that. This is how you would go about it using javascript.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }); 
</script>
```